# Facebook iOS Api call fails on relogin, but isSessionValid is YES

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, authentication, facebook-graph-api

i have a strange problem with the fb mobile api. Im using the latest git version.

In my app, a user can login to facebook on app start.
If a user hasnt a valid session (eg, is not logged in, checked with loaded FBCredentials in user defaults), the facebook authorize code is called. The user logs in, and he returns to my app (new token + time saved in the user defaults). After that, I call a simple /me request. I get data from facebook, everythings fine.

But now heres the catch: The user closes the app (still logged in). The user reopens the app. My app checks if the user has a valid session (again, checked with loaded FBCredentials in user defaults), and it returns YES (Thats what Ive expected). But this time, the api call immediately after login/starting the app is returning nothing! All further api calls return nothing aswell.

If the user logs out within the app ([facebook logout:self];) and then logs in again, the api calls are working. So I assume my codes not working with the loading credentials at app start.

Heres my Controller, which is responsible for fb connect.

```
//
//  FacebookController.h
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "FBConnect.h"

@interface FacebookController : NSObject <FBRequestDelegate, FBSessionDelegate> {
    Facebook *facebook;
    NSArray *permissions;

}

@property(nonatomic, retain) Facebook *facebook;

+ (FacebookController *)instance;
- (void)loginToFacebook;
- (void)loggedIn;
- (void)logoutOfFacebook;

@end
```

And the implementation:

```
//
//  FacebookController.m
//

#import "FacebookController.h"
#import "MyAppAppDelegate.h"

static NSString* FBAppId = @"...";

@interface FacebookController()

    - (void)loadFBCredentials;
    - (void)saveFBCredentials;

@end


@implementation FacebookController

@synthesize facebook;

+ (FacebookController *)instance {
    static FacebookController *instance = nil;
    if (!instance) {
        instance = [[FacebookController alloc] init];
    }
    return instance;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (!facebook) {
        facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:FBAppId];
        [self loadFBCredentials];
    }
    return self;
}

// Show the authorization dialog.
- (void)loginToFacebook {
    if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
        [facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];
    } else {
        [self loggedIn];
    }
}

// Show the authorization dialog.
- (void)logoutOfFacebook {
    [facebook logout:self];
}

- (void)loggedIn {
    // Api call.
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"/me" andDelegate:self];
}

// Called when the user has logged in successfully.
- (void)fbDidLogin {
    // Save Credentials.
    [self saveFBCredentials];
    [self loggedIn];
}

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

}

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

}

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
    NSLog(@"Got request");
    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSLog(@"count : %d ", [result count]);
        NSArray* resultArray = [result allObjects];

        NSLog(@"count : %d ", [result count]);
        result = [resultArray objectAtIndex:0];
    }
}

// Called when the request logout has succeeded.
- (void)fbDidLogout {   
    [self saveFBCredentials];

    [(MyAppAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate showModalLoginView:YES]; 
}

- (void)loadFBCredentials {
    NSLog(@"Loading.");
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
        && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
        facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        facebook.expirationDate = (NSDate *) [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    }
}

- (void)saveFBCredentials {
    NSLog(@"Saving.");
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [facebook release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask for offline_access permission and use the access token key generated inorder to avoid the scenario of session invalid.

Comment: It's actually not what I've searched for, but for now, this helps me out. Thank you!